# how to translate text without using google api?

Tags: android

is there any alternative to translate text form one language to another (like english,spanish etc.) of google api as they are paid?
i have used LOCALE but they do not translate perfectly for ex. hello in English remains hello in spanish also any hep will be very helpful. thank you in advance.

suppose i want to build something like this.
THIS IS NOT MY APP....
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/73620ad386.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when submit your App to Google Play you get an option to translate, I'm not sure on the working, but the other alternative is to translate all the text yourself and use separate values.xml for each lang.

EDIT:

[Mygengo Translation API](http://mygengo.com/api/)
[Microsoft Translator APIs](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/)
[Speaklite Translate API](http://www.speaklike.com/access-professional-translation-via-api/)
[WebServiceX Translate API](http://www.webservicex.net/ws/wsdetails.aspx?wsid=63)

Comment: what i meant is like a dictionary , in which you can change the language of text with a click of button it has to be dynamic

Comment: Oh, you could set up a main bank of words in an Sqlite database and then check to see if those words equal the sentences inserted by the user and then the next rows could have the other language counterparts. If I answered your question, you can always accept it.

Comment: thanxs bluecat but that will be too tedious.. is there no other option like a website from where i can translate the string?? or any other option??

Comment: Not really, I'm sure there's some other translate APIs out there, but Google will be your best best, I know it goes against your title, but Google has the best translate engine and rewriting an engine would be much effort for little gain. https://developers.google.com/translate/

Comment: http://translate.google.com/translate_tools can't i use this?? i don't know ??

Comment: @charlie No, I think that's just a HTML 5 form, I doubt it would work with Android. Also, please accept my answer if fulfils your question.

Comment: but will these axtensions work on android??

Comment: There might be an API for Android, but there's bound to be a Web API that you make requests to.