# Translate English text to arabic

Tags: android

I want to convert the English string which I get from a JSON response to Arabic string. (can't use another `@String` for Arabic as the Strings are dynamic, straight from the web service)

I don't want to use the Google translate API as it is paid and has a limit of 2M chars/day.

All I need to know is that if there is any API available for that or any link which I can use to fullfill my requirement.

Comment: Translating via machine is always going to be fairly inaccurate. For a native speaker you can probably make out the meaning, but it certainly won't be natural.

Comment: I do know this risk but the strings which I need to handle are quite simple and generic words like, hi,hello etc,so it should work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this link [BING API](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis)

```
string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?appId=" + appId + "&text=" + tobetranslated + "&from=" + fromLang + "&to=" + toLang;
```

Then have a web request you will get the desired output

Comment: Thanks for this,but I was wondering if there is any api available so that i can copy my english strings and convert them later into arabic which will be an offline process.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Bing API
http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis

This is free at the moment.

Comment: btw, have you tried this
[stack over flow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816646/how-to-translate-text-without-using-google-api?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, I believe I have.But the answers were not meant for my present problem